# Why is my PHP code being run every time the website is loaded?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a userregistration.php page that for some reason is adding NULL usernames/passwords into my MYSQL database every time the page is reloaded. It's as if the script is being run before the submit button is being pressed. Here is the code:

```
<?php 

include("dbconnect.php"); 


$firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];

  $personcon=$conn;


  $bbsSQL = "INSERT INTO TBLUSERS (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$username', '$password')"; 

  $personinfo=oci_parse($personcon,$bbsSQL); 
  oci_execute($personinfo); 


  oci_free_statement($personinfo);
  oci_close($personcon);

 echo "Thank you for registration";

?>


<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="RegisterUser.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="right">First name:</td>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">Last name:</td>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="lastname" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">Email:</td>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">User name:</td>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">Password:</td>
<td align="left"><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
<input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" name="Reset"/></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me solve this? Obviously I only want a new user to be created when the "submit" button is pressed. Thanks!

Comment: Just remove action="RegisterUser.php" and write if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { after db file and close after your echo statement }

Comment: I actually tried this but it doesn't seem to run the PHP code at all when I do this.

Comment: You need to understand the basic logic behind PHP, PHP is run everytime it's called, meaning if you have a site where php code is included, it _will_ be executed, to avoid unintentional inserts for example, you'll have to produce a check that you actually want to do the database insert, which one way of doing it is as SunilPachlangia mentioned and check if your form as been submitted.

Comment: Perfect it's all solved now. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call a php function on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403736/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-button-click)

Comment: done! thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the code that creates the account in an if() statement that checks if there is contents in $_POST. Something like this:

```
if ( isset($_POST['Submit']) ) {
    $firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];        

    $personcon=$conn;    


    $bbsSQL = "INSERT INTO TBLUSERS (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$username', '$password')";         

    $personinfo=oci_parse($personcon,$bbsSQL); 
    oci_execute($personinfo);     


    oci_free_statement($personinfo);
    oci_close($personcon);        

    echo "Thank you for registration";
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much, I actually had this code but I had 'submit' instead of 'Submit'. Perfect!

Comment: Yep, it's gotta match the name you defined for it in the form.